# Downloaded path for Gradle comple statement

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have created my android project and have many gradle compile statement. But when I move my project to another location it is fetching file from gradle compile statement from Internet which is already downloaded, which consumes lots of development time.
Can any one help me locate exact path where all dependencies get downloaded from gradle compile. So that I can directly use those dependencies in my project and save my time.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you directly reference a local file in gradle instead of a URL? If yes, simply download the files once and put it in a shared folder.

Comment: Compile statement like     
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
add same statement in different project makes it downloadable in every project. I want to download these dependencies in one project and use in others.

Comment: thanks i got my answer